# Ubuntu vm: No network interface, no UI

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, network-interface

I have an Ubuntu VMWare virtual machine that stopped having an internet connection after a forced a shutdown.

Upon inspection there were no connections in the Network panel of Settings.

I found this previous superuser question: [Ubuntu: Missing network interface and no UI](https://superuser.com/q/1192557/955345) and miraculously the one and only answer worked!

Only problem is that every time I boot the vm back up I have to do the whole procedure again.

Worth noting that I don't have an eth0 interface but I have one called ens33 and that's what I used for the commands.

Does anyone know what's going on or how I can just automate the procedure so that it runs every time I boot? (ugly solution, I know, but I spent hours researching and that answer is the only thing I found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to modify the network configuration for this interface so it automatically comes up and runs dhcp.

I am not sure which network configuration strategy your linux is using; your answer depends on which of these files exists:

**/etc/network/interfaces**

Given Ubuntu, it's probably this strategy.

Put these two lines into the file if they are not present already, and remove other lines related to ens33:

```
auto ens33
iface ens33 inet dhcp
```

Note: If you see the line "source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg", you may also have a "/etc/network/interfaces.d/ens33.cfg" file. If you see this line in your interfaces file, it would be more appropriate to put your changes into the ens33.cfg file.

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33.cfg**

In the future most distributions should be shifting to this configuration strategy so I am putting it for future users. This should be the contents of the file, and probably nothing else.

```
DEVICE=ens33
BOOTPROTO=dhcp 
ONBOOT=yes
```

If you are still encountering issues, please post the contents of these files.

Answer (score 0):

Restor configuration Virtual Network Editor to default.

This link helpme
https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/No-more-network-in-VMs/td-p/2926219

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1193095)