# I have ubuntu-server running but when I reboot it doesn get IP addres

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

When I run this command:

`ifconfig`

I get:

`lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 272  bytes 19712 (19.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 272  bytes 19712 (19.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

no IP adress for ethernet interface

but when I run :

`sudo dhclient -v enp1s0`

I get IP

How can I make this automated

Comment: Is there a DHCP server on the network? Have you checked the logs for the DHCP server?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the interface enp1s0 doesn't show up in your initial ifconfig, the problem isn't dhcp. It seems like you have this interface set to disabled on boot, and when you run dhclient, in addition to getting an IP, it brings up the interface.

I would check your interface configuration file `/etc/network/interfaces` to make sure you haven't disabled this interface inadvertently.

See here for more instructions: [superuser.com/a/1368111/953717](http://superuser.com/a/1368111/953717)

Comment: That didnt work for me do you maybe know what next should I try

Comment: does the interface appear in ifconfig and take an IP if you simply run `sudo ifup enp1s0`?

Comment: i run command sudo dhclient -v enp1s0

Comment: I am asking you to run another command. ifup only enables the interface and nothing else. I believe your are using an over complicated command. By the way, can you add the output of `sudo dhclient -v enp1s0` to your question?

Comment: Dude thanks you help me a lot it works now after reboot

Comment: My original advice about the config files worked?